# Android Wear Notification Page Actions

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have an app that kicks off a notification on a Wear device (the notification is created and shown on the Wear device).

What I want to do is have the "first" notification page display some high level info (app name, scroll to see more, etc...), and then have a list of pages containing content after that.

That works fine. The issue is that I want to attach an `Action` to each page (to kick off a `PendingIntent`). However, no matter what I try, I can't get the page to perform the `Action`.

I've tried:

```
setContentIntent
addAction
addAction and extend(new Notification.WearableExtender().setContentAction(0))
```

Anyone have any ideas?

I'm using `Notification`, not `NotificationCompat`, but I don't think that should make a difference.

**UPDATE:** I'm creating the notification on the watch. Here is the code I use:

```
private void createNotifications(ArrayList<Thing> things) {
    DataApi data = Wearable.DataApi;

    int notificationId = 0;

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification.Builder mainBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.default_icon)
            .setContentTitle("Things")
            .setContentText("Swipe to see your things")
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

    List<Notification> pages = new ArrayList<>(things.size());

    for(Thing thing : things) {
        pages.add(createNotificationPageForThing(data, thing, notificationId).build());
        notificationId++;
    }

    Notification n = new Notification.WearableExtender().addPages(pages).extend(mainBuilder).build();
    nm.notify(notificationId, n);
}

private Notification.Builder createNotificationPageForThing(DataApi data, Thing thing, int notificationId) {
    Asset bitmapAsset = getBitmapAsset(data, contact);

    Intent thingIntent = new Intent(this, WearDetailActivity.class);
    thingIntent.putExtra(WearDetailActivity.DETAIL_EXTRA, thing);
    PendingIntent thingPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notificationId, thingIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification.Action action = new Notification.Action(R.drawable.ic_action_social_person, "More details",  thingPendingIntent);
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_social_person)
            .setContentTitle(thing.getDisplayName())
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .addAction(action)
            .extend(new Notification.WearableExtender().setContentAction(0));

    if(bitmapAsset != null) {
        try {
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                    data.getFdForAsset(connection.getClient(), bitmapAsset).await().getInputStream());
            builder.setLargeIcon(b);
        } catch (Throwable ignore) {}
    }

    return builder;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I doubt this is possible (or even desirable if possible, for UI consistency reasons). In all the apps I've seen, actions are supposed to be shown as distinct screens, and none of the pages are actionable. But maybe I'll be proven wrong. :)

Comment: @matiash I hope so. It would be pretty awesome if this worked, as my only other option is to stack notifications (which seems to have a limit of 12).

Comment: Does adding an Action to each page (through that page's WearableExtender, I presume) actually render anything related to the action on that page?

Answer (score 0):

@Eliezer, reading at the following line I did not understand what exactly is the behaviour you're experiencing ... explaining it in details might be helpful to debug your problem.

> However, no matter what I try, I can't get the page to perform the `Action`.

Using `.addAction()` should work in your case. You'd want to use `WearableExtender` if you were creating the notification from the device, not the watch itself. Just to confirm something obvious - you're passing the .addAction a `PendingIntent` right?

Here's a code snippet from one of my applications, which accomplishes exactly what you're aiming for - I have just "Swipe for actions" text in the first page, and the next 2 pages perform different actions.

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

 Intent openIntent = new Intent(this, CommonWearIntentService.class);
 openIntent.setAction(CommonWearIntentService.ACTION_OPEN_ON_PHONE);
 PendingIntent openPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, openIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

 Intent addTransactionIntent = new Intent(this, CommonWearIntentService.class);
 addTransactionIntent.setAction(CommonWearIntentService.ACTION_ADD_TRANSACTION);
 PendingIntent addTransactionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, addTransactionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

 builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setContentText(getString(R.string.swipe_for_actions))
        .addAction(R.drawable.add_transaction, getString(R.string.add_transaction), addTransactionPendingIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.common_full_open_on_phone, getString(R.string.common_open_on_phone), openPendingIntent)
        .setVibrate(new long[]{500, 500, 500, 1000})
        .setLights(Color.BLUE, 3000, 3000)
        .setOngoing(true);

notificationManager.notify(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I updated my question to show the code that I am using. It doesn't look like the code you posted is using pages.

Answer (score -1):

Per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/pages.html), you must use [NotificationCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html).  After you switch to that setContentIntent() looks to be the right way to set the PendingIntent.

Example from the linked docs:

```
// Create builder for the main notification
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_message)
        .setContentTitle("Page 1")
        .setContentText("Short message")
        .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent);

// Create a big text style for the second page
BigTextStyle secondPageStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
secondPageStyle.setBigContentTitle("Page 2")
               .bigText("A lot of text...");

// Create second page notification
Notification secondPageNotification =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setStyle(secondPageStyle)
        .build();

// Add second page with wearable extender and extend the main notification
Notification twoPageNotification =
        new WearableExtender()
                .addPage(secondPageNotification)
                .extend(notificationBuilder)
                .build();

// Issue the notification
notificationManager =
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, twoPageNotification);
```

Comment: I'll try that, but I'm pretty sure that's not the issue, since I'm creating the Notifications on Wear itself (not on the handset at all).

Comment: Just tried using `NotificationCompat` and that didn't do it. Thanks anyways.